# How to get reference to containing object if I have a reference to a property in C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, customvalidator

I am implementing a custom validation (MVC DataAnnotations) and I have a class structure like this

```
class Parent()
{

    public Child ChildObject1{get;set;}
    public Child ChildObject2{get;set;}

}

class Child()
{

    public GrandChild GrandChildObject1{get;set;}
    public GrandChild GrandChildObject2{get;set;}
       etc.
}

class GrandChild()
{
    public Flags FlagsThatAffectValidationOnSomeProperties {get;set;}

    [CustomValidation]
    private string _myProperty;
}
```

I want to code the custom validation and I need to get access to the FlagsThatAffectValidationOnSomeProperties object.  I pass in the reference to 'Parent' instance in the 'ValidationContext' object of the IsValid override

```
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        if (!validationContext.Items.ContainsKey(ContextItemKeys.Parent))
            return ValidationResult.Success;


        Parent parent = (Parent)validationContext.Items[ContextItemKeys.Parent];
```

...

but how do I get a reference to GrandchildObject1.FlagsThatAffectValidationOnSomeProperties so that I can properly validate the _myProperty that is passed in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `validationContext.ObjectInstance` to get the current instance of the object being validated and use reflection to access the property value. You can also include additional checks to ensure that the instance is really an instance of Grand Child or not if you need.

```
protected virtual object GetPropertyValue(ValidationContext validationContext, string propertyName)
{
   var properties = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

   var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName);
   if (property == null)
      return null;

   var propertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
   return propertyValue;
}

var propertyValue = GetPropertyValue(validationContext, "FlagsThatAffectValidationOnSomeProperties");
```

// Cast the value to enum if not null and use the value